# C++ std::setprecision in C#

Tags: c#

I'm picking up C# by porting some legacy C++ code and would like to keep the output identical. What used to be something along the lines of

```
output << std::setprecision(10) << (double) value;
```

I figured would now be

```
output.Write("{0:F10}", value);
```

But this didn't do the trick. Specifically values `> 1` would get more digits. A common online suggestion was to `Math.Round` first, but this appends zeroes if the total length was `< 10`.

So I put together:

```
    // std::setprecision is not exactly the same as ":F10", mirror original behavior
    static string setPrecision(double value) {
        string ret = value.ToString();

        // Don't just Substring(0, 11), we need to apply rounding,
        // and don't always do this, we don't want to append zeroes,
        // for 10 digits + period, with 0.. not counting for total
        if(ret.Length > digits + 1)
            ret = Math.Round(value, digits + (value < 1 ? 1 : 0) - ret.IndexOf('.')).ToString();

        return ret;
    }
```

where `digits` is a static constant; I could certainly make this a variable, but for this project in particular it makes little sense to do so.

Still, this seems overly complicated. Is there a more elegant way to get the traditional behavior?

As requested some example I/O

```
// C++
double test = 0; out << std::setprecision(10);
test = 0.123456780;   out << test << '\n';
test = 0.0123456781;  out << test << '\n';
test = 0.11234567819; out << test << '\n';
test = 1.00234567899; out << test << '\n';

// C#
double test = 0;            
test = 0.123456780;   output.WriteLine(setPrecision(test));
test = 0.0123456781;   output.WriteLine(setPrecision(test));
test = 0.11234567819; output.WriteLine(setPrecision(test));
test = 1.00234567899; output.WriteLine(setPrecision(test));
```

Both produce:

```
0.12345678
0.0123456781
0.1123456782
1.002345679
```

And meanwhile I noticed all heading zeroes don't seem to count towards the total rather than just the first;

```
// C++
test = 0.012345678906;    out << test << '\n'; // 0.01234567891
test = 0.0012345678906;   out << test << '\n'; // 0.001234567891
test = 0.00012345678906;  out << test << '\n'; // 0.0001234567891

// C#
test = 0.012345678906;   output.WriteLine(setPrecision(test)); // 0.0123456789
test = 0.0012345678906;  output.WriteLine(setPrecision(test)); // 0.0012345679
test = 0.00012345678906; output.WriteLine(setPrecision(test)); // 0.0001234568
```

I'll have to correct that if there isn't a more straightforward solution.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do. Can you give us some example input and output so I can piece it together?

Comment: So to sum it up: show 10 numbers behind the comma and remove trailing zeros?

Comment: Show up to 10 non-zero numbers, either before or after the comma, without trailing zeroes, is a better summary I think.

Comment: You might need to refresh the page, I accidentally a zero.

Comment: So after seeing the last edit your method does not return the correct output, does it ?

Comment: No, it's not perfect. But before spending more time on this I wonder if this the is best _approach_ to mimicking C/C++'s behavior. I was fully expecting a simple formatting tag to be available. Similarly seeing the number of search results for this, I'm clearly not the first to run into the problem. Finding an answer remains elusive, however.

Comment: I don't know the C# standard library well enough to help you, but [`ToString` can take formatting options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx). Anyways, I'm not sure this is the right place to ask this question, since it is a very language/library specific question. Perhaps you'd get better feedback on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to print the number with a specific number of significant digits.  You can simply use the G format string to specify the number of digits to use.

```
output.Write("{0:G10}", value);
```

Comment: I knew there had to be something trivial! Apparently the key search words I was missing were [general format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#GFormatString).

Answer (score 3):

What you are referring to is [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures). It's actually pretty easy to calculate:

```
    public static string FormatSignificantFigures(double number, int figures)
    {
        int e = 0;

        while (number >= 10.0)
        {
            e += 1;
            number /= 10;
        }

        while (number < 1.0)
        {
            e -= 1;
            number *= 10;
        }

        figures--;

        number = Math.Round(number, figures);

        figures += 0 - e;
        while (e > 0)
        {
            number *= 10;
            e -= 1;
        }

        while (e < 0)
        {
            number /= 10;
            e += 1;
        }

        if (figures < 0)
        {
            figures = 0;
        }

        return number.ToString($"f{figures}");
    }
```

Basically, the first two `while` loops normalize our number to a value between `[1,10)`.

Then, we round the number to the number of significant figures (minus 1, remembering that we already have a significant figure of `1` at the front). We then restore it, and the last line is a C#6.0 string interpolation for:

```
return number.ToString("f" + figures);
```

The test code was:

```
    public static void _Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] numbers = new double[] { 0.012345678906, 0.0012345678906, 0.00012345678906, 0.123456789012, 1.234567890124, 12.345678901234, 123.45678901234, 1234.5678901234, 12345.678901234 };

        foreach (double number in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{number}: {FormatSignificantFigures(number, 3)}");
        }
    }
```

Results:

> ```
> 0.012345678906: 0.0123
> 0.0012345678906: 0.00123
> 0.00012345678906: 0.000123
> 0.123456789012: 0.123
> 1.234567890124: 1.23
> 12.345678901234: 12.3
> 123.45678901234: 123
> 1234.5678901234: 1230
> 12345.678901234: 12300
> ```

Note: this was a quick answer, I'm going to extract some of this out to another function which doesn't return a string momentarily, but this should get you started.

Comment: I just gave it a spin but noticed `0.12345678` with a `figures` set to `10` resulting in `0.1234567800` - it appended zeroes. So I'm not going to accept this answer just yet. But interesting approach, I'll go play around with it a little.

Comment: @Meeuwisse so just use `return number.ToString($"f{figures}").TrimEnd(new char[] {'0'});`

Comment: I expect you'd then break printing `10`. I wanted to double-check and noticed this produces `10.`, which brings up yet another interesting edge-case.

Comment: This implementation mimics C++ implementation very well. The rounding is however not fully ok.  1267.125 to 6 significant digits is giving 1267.12 although it should be 1267.13